# How are sms stored in any phones?

Tags: java, java-me, sms

I just wanted to know how all the sms in the phone stored internally?? and how do i access this internal files?

Comment: @zengr its java-me, It was typo.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on various flavors of phone OSs like Symbian, android, iOS

For example: Android saves its SMS's in `/data/data/com.android.providers/telephony/databases/mmssms.db`
[iPhone](http://www.geekology.co.za/blog/2009/05/exporting-iphone-sms-message-database-to-csv-file/) also used SQLite database internally. `/var/root/Library/SMS/sms.db`

It's a lightweight embedded SQLite database.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Wammu](http://wammu.eu) project. It can access phonebooks, SMS, calendars, etc. on many cell phone types.

Comment: Oh! Question is about *how* are they stored internally.

Comment: And the second part of your question is 'how do I access these internal files'...

Comment: "and how do i access this internal files?".. remove the DV.

Comment: @eumiro: Access the files. I thought Wammu will let you access the *content* of these files.

Comment: thnks for de reply...i jus wanted 2 as to hw do v access these sms files so dat i can parse de contents..

Answer (score 0):

Text files in older phones while newer ones may use light weight databases. (Details about Android and iOS in [zengr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975435/how-are-sms-stored-in-any-phones/3975568#3975568).)

If possible you can browse the file system on your phone. It the phone does not allow that then you will probably have to root it.

Comment: @zengr: My old Sony Ericsson W810i did.

Comment: I think SE uses Sony Ericsson Java Platform or Symbiam (it has an embedded db) but not sure about SE J2ME OS.

Comment: @zengr: And phones like Nokia 1100 too (I'm guessing this one, not sure). W810i didn't have Symbian et al. :)