# How is SMS stored internally in ordinary Nokia mobile phones?

Tags: java, mobile, sms, symbian

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975435/how-are-sms-stored-in-any-phones). But I want to know how basic mobiles internally store SMS? How can we programmatically manipulate SMS by code, as we don't have an option of connecting it to the PC.

Update: I'm asking for accessing SMS programmatically, not mobile internals.

Comment: It is probably off-topic, because it is not about computers, but about mobile phone internals. See the FAQ, http://stackoverflow.com/faq .

Answer (score -1):

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS#Message_size), an SMS message is always exactly 1120 bits, and as for encodings...

> Short messages can be encoded using a variety of alphabets: the
>   default GSM 7-bit alphabet, the 8-bit data alphabet, and the 16-bit
>   UTF-16 alphabet. Depending on which alphabet the subscriber has
>   configured in the handset, this leads to the maximum individual short
>   message sizes of 160 7-bit characters, 140 8-bit characters, or 70
>   16-bit characters. GSM 7-bit alphabet support is mandatory for GSM
>   handsets and network elements, but characters in languages such as
>   Arabic, Chinese, Korean, Japanese or Cyrillic alphabet languages (e.g.
>   Russian, Serbian, Bulgarian, etc.) must be encoded using the 16-bit
>   UTF-16 character encoding.